# How to display Select with parent and child data in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have an array that get from API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "978",
        "name_en": "Dislplay name",
        "name_ru": "Dislplay name",
        "child": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "657",
        "name_en": "Dislplay name",
        "name_ru": "Dislplay name",
        "child": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "342",
        "name_en": "Dislplay name",
        "name_ru": "Dislplay name",
        "child": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "code": "435",
                "name_en": "Dislplay name",
                "name_ru": "Dislplay name",
                "spec_code": "122"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "code": "097",
                "name_en": "Dislplay name",
                "name_ru": "Dislplay name",
                "spec_code": "122"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "code": "665",
                "name_en": "Dislplay name",
                "name_ru": "Dislplay name",
                "spec_code": "122"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

And I want to display this with select functionality, but I don't know how can I display the child items, I can display it, but not selectable. In project, I use React, Redux and Material-UI

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, you should really try this on your own first and if you're still stuck or have an issue, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a question for what you've tried and a detailed description about what isn't working. Include error messages and any stacktraces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with `<ListSubheader>` component, you can read about grouping select in the official [Material-UI docs](https://material-ui.com/ru/components/selects/#grouping)